# VBA Code works on Windows but 1004 Runtime error on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf

The code I have is below, it works absolutely fine on Windows but the Mac users I've given it to seem to have trouble using it and I'm unfamiliar with VBA on Macs and all the troubleshooting I've tried to do hasn't helped.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()

 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim fname As String
 Dim location As String
Dim surname As String


 Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
    Filename = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
 End If

      'Added variable here just incase you wanted to change it at some point
 location = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
 topic = Filename


 'Loop through each sheet
 For Each sh In Worksheets


'Select Sheet
sh.Select


'Set filename
fname = sh.Name & " " & Range("A3")
    
'Save document
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=location & topic & " " & fname & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

fname = Empty
 Next
    
 End Sub
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: Also, since we need to repro, tell us how to set up the workbook so the code will run correctly - the first time.

Comment: The error occurs in the save document section. It highlights the whole 2 lines.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to save each sheet as a pdf in the same location as the original file with the excel file name, sheet name and cell A3 as the filename for the pdf